# Do we really need std::error_category and std::error_condition?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, error-code

So, on my journey to understand how `std::error_code` works I'm starting to wonder if we really need `std::error_condition` and `std::error_category`. I'm trying to implement what's in [this](https://ned14.github.io/outcome/tutorial/error_code/) and [this](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-5.html) tutorial and the amount of work is non-trivial along with it being fairly fragile (I'm currently stuck trying to figure out why this code causes linking errors with duplicate symbols.

Isn't it easier to subclass `std::error_code`, add a `message` property & method and then let `std::error_code` be comparable to an enum where error codes are defined? I'm struggling to understand why I need `std::error_category` and `std::error_condition` at all.

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle errors in C++, there is no one true way. If you don't need it, don't use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main advantage is that `error_code` is a copyable type that can be handed around from library to library without having to involve any dynamic memory allocation or templating, making it very light-weight, and easy to work with.

If you are writing a fully self-contained project, then yes, error codes and categories seem overly complicated when you could just have your own type.

However, things change when writing a library meant to be used by other people (like ASIO, since you linked think-async.com). You can have a library receive an `error_code` instance, and it will be able to pass it around cleanly and efficiently without having to know anything about the code that is using the library, or having to make every error-handling function be templated on the error type.

In that context, error categories are important when dealing with multiple error sources, as a given error-code could mean two different things based on the source of the error.

**Edit:** Notice, in your first link, how categories are actually singletons. This is done in the service of maintaining lightweightness, since copying a pointer to an object that is guaranteed to never be deleted or modified is cheap, memory-safe and thread-safe.

Comment: I would add that it also makes it easy to transport custom error codes via standard exception types like `std::system_error`. Client code that uses your library doesn't need to know anything about your custom error category. They could just catch `std::system_error` and by calling *generic* methods of `std::error_code`, they could write it to a log file, where the error value, the name of the error category you defined, and the string message you defined in your error category would appear. Much better than just outputting "error code 123", where nobody knows to which context it belongs.