# Is std::error_category usable with dynamic messages?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-code

I'm developing a library that talks to a remote system and while it returns a finite and known number of error codes, the messages may change in unpredictable ways.

So I'm [exploring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868539/do-we-really-need-stderror-category-and-stderror-condition) `std::error_code` as a way to provide users of my library a way to handle errors native to C++, instead of rolling out my own code. I cannot throw exceptions.

[Tutorials](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-5.html) on the use of `std::error_category` always show that a static instance is used with hardcoded messages being returned depending on the error code.

But what if we have dynamic messages that cannot be cached? How can we link a specific message to a specific instance of `std::error_code`?

Comment: Nobody uses `std::error_code`.

Comment: @o11c They should tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't really do that.

`error_code` is meant to be a copyable value type. If custom messages were allowed, copying an error would involve doing a deep copy of the message data, or maintaining a ref-count.

This would make error codes too heavy to be used in many application/library inner loops, basically forcing programmers to use a different error handling mechanism for that part of the code, rendering `error_code` essentially pointless.

You might be able to get around that by using a thread local error state (like the old school `errno`), but I'd recommend against that, since it would prevent you from storing errors for any length of time.

Comment: Is there a C++ way of handling errors besides std::error_code and exceptions?

Comment: @ruipacheco Sure! C++ is a flexible enough language that whatever error handling scheme you come up with is probably implementable. I personally really like Andrei Alexandrescu's `expected<>` scheme, but I've yet to see it used in production.

Comment: @ruipacheco My experience is that the reason for failure is only ever usefull for debugging more often than not, so returning a simple success/failure state, combined with a simple write-to-log at the failure site is generally all you need, really.

Comment: I mean a generic interface everyone recognizes as error handling. As the asio examples show, HTTP error codes but I'd like to return dynamic messages with each error code.

Comment: @ruipacheco You might as well just use exceptions at that point.

Comment: I can't, I may need to queue a number of errors from a remote system and allow the user to return them when it suits him/her.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152917/discussion-between-ruipacheco-and-frank).